# How do I use an Ubuntu laptop as an external monitor for a Mac?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, display, external-display, laptop-display

The main machine that I'm using is a Mac, and the other one is a Sony Vaio running Ubuntu.

Does anyone have an idea how to use the Ubuntu laptop as a second monitor?

Comment: I have never heard of using a laptop has a monitor for another machine.

Answer (score 0):

With another Mac, you can put it into target display mode and it will function as an external monitor when a video source is input.

The Ubuntu machine would need to be configured in a similar way using some custom software.